# AngularJS - Set a variable with a directive similarly to ng-controller and ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

In ng-controller, you can declare 'ExampleCtrl as example', then use 'example' as a reference in your HTML. In ng-repeat, you can declare 'example in examples', then use 'example' to reference the data used for each iteration of the repeat.

Is there a way to manually set a variable using a directive in the same manner that ng-repeat would, except without repeating? What would be the easiest way to do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you give an html example of what you'd like to see?

Comment: look at "isolate scope"

Comment: Moogs, something like this

Comment: <custom-directive some-attribute="controller.data as variable">
     <!-- Template will be loaded -->
</custom-directive>

<custom-directive ng-repeat="variable in controller.array">
     <!-- Same template will be loaded for each entry in the array -->
</custom-directive>

I want the template to be able to manipulate whatever is set as 'variable'.

Comment: if you are going to add code to your question, please edit the question to include the code.  Code samples in comments are VERY difficult to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With angular you can use isolate scope to modify the name of data that is passed into the directive.

So rather than ..

```
<custom-directive some-attribute="controller.data as variable">
```

You could do ..

```
<custom-directive some-attribute="controller.data">
```

By setting up your directive as ..

```
angular.module('app').directive('myPane', function() {
  return {
     scope: {
       variable: '=someAttribute'
     }
  };
});
```

your directive template could then refer to 'variable', like...

```
<div>{{variable}}</div>
```

You will only be able to refer to 'variable' in the template. As this isolate scope it belong to the directive

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so much, that helps a lot! Followup question: in your example, would the scope definition of variable in custom directive conflict with variable definition in ng-repeat if I were to structure the HTML like this?
<custom-directive ng-repeat="variable in controller.array"></custom-directive>

Comment: Firstly, if you have two separate custom-directive's the isolate scope is specific to each directive, so it is not shared. Secondly, if I understand you correctly, it might be better to pass 'variable' into the directive, something like this `<custom-directive ng-repeat="variable in controller.array" some-attribute="variable"></custom-directive>`

Comment: If I did what you suggest, would there not be a conflict between the some-attribute's variable and ng-repeat's variable? Which would output for {{variable}}? I want to be able to use the custom directive twice--once with some-attribute and once with ng-repeat--all while using the same reference variable in the template.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood your last comment. If I understand you correctly, you're saying I should pass the ng-repeat variable into the custom directive's scope, to ensure they don't conflict. I'm sure that would work, but I'd still like to know for the future which directive's scope is being referenced in that instance.

Comment: Not entirely sure I get the last comment. Basically, what we do is separate the scope inside a directive from the scope outside, and then map the outer scope to a directive's inner scope. This is called isolate scope. The two scopes can be connected, but are isolated and don't mess with each other. The magic of Angular!